# How to append additional data in a specified div using php / ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know if there is a way to display an external php file after clicking on a link, and then display another external file right below(not INSTEAD of) it after a different link was clicked. Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html>  
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-   1.2.6.pack.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>   
</head>  
<body>   
<div id="menu">  
<ul>  
<li id="home"><a href="#downloads">DOWNLOADS</a></li>  
<li id="tutorials"><a href="#errors">ERRORS</a></li>  
</ul>   
</div>  
<div id="content">    
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**core.js**

```
//On load page, init the timer which check if the there are anchor changes each 300 ms
$().ready(function(){
setInterval("checkAnchor()", 100);
});
var currentAnchor = null;
//Function which chek if there are anchor changes, if there are, sends the ajax    petition
function checkAnchor(){
//Check if it has changes
if(currentAnchor != document.location.hash){
    currentAnchor = document.location.hash;
    //if there is not anchor, the loads the default section
    if(!currentAnchor)
        query = "page=1";
    else
    {
        //Creates the  string callback. This converts the url URL/#main&id=2 in URL/?section=main&id=2
        var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
        //Get the section
        var page = splits[0];
        delete splits[0];
        //Create the params string
        var params = splits.join('&');
        var query = "page=" + page + params;
    }
    //Send the petition
    $("#loading").show();
    $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
}
```

**downloads.php**

```
<b>DOWNLOADS</b>
```

**errors.php**

```
<b>ERRORS</b>
```

**callbacks.php**

```
<?php  
//used to simulate more waiting for load the content, remove on yor projects!  
sleep(1);  
//Captures the petition and load the suitable section  
switch($_GET['page']){  
case "errors": include 'errors.php'; break;
case "downloads": include 'downloads.php'; break;

default: include 'downloads.php'; break;

}  
?>
```

This works perfectly except it uses a switch and I want to be able to see both errors.php and downloads.php at the same time, not only one or the other.

**EDIT**

**Pseudo code** to make it clearer:

If download is clicked show download.php only. If error is clicked show error.php only(right after downloads.php) and don't remove downloads.php or any other external file that may or may not be included on the main page already.

Any suggestions?

p.s. I've looked through many, many threads about this and that's why I can't post all the code I've tried (sorry I can't include links either, last time my question was downvoted for doing that...>:/) so I can promise I've done my homework.

p.s.s. If you think this deserves a down vote please be kind enough to explain why. I'm open to criticism but just thumbs down is not helpful at all.

**EDIT:**

Updated **core.js** to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu li a').click(function() {
    var currentAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
    if(!currentAnchor)
        var query = "page=1";
    else
    {
        var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
        //Get the section
        var page = splits[0];
        delete splits[0];
        //Create the params string
        var params = splits.join('&');
        var query = "page=" + page + params;
    }
    //Send the petition
    $("#loading").show();
    $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
        $("#loading").hide();
    });       
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: upon examining the code, the `core.js` seems to be the crudest way of sniffing a click event. A simple `$(selector).click()` would have setup the mouse event to listen for clicks and react accordingly

Comment: Basically replace $('#content').html(data) with $('#content').append(data) and everything will work the way you explained in the last part of a very long confusing day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

[The confusing parts removed here]

--

EDIT:

**core.js** (revised)

```
//On load page, init the timer which check if the there are anchor changes each 300 ms
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li a').click(function() {
        var currentAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
        if(!currentAnchor)
            var query = "page=1";
        else
        {
            var splits = currentAnchor.substring(1).split('&');
            //Get the section
            var page = splits[0];
            delete splits[0];
            //Create the params string
            var params = splits.join('&');
            var query = "page=" + page + params;
        }
        //Send the petition
        $("#loading").show();
        $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
            $("#loading").hide();
        });       
        return false;
    });
}​​​);​​​
```

--

EDIT:

This one will "**append**" data [coming from either *downloads* or *errors*] to the existing content.

```
        $.get("callbacks.php",query, function(data){
            $("#content").append(data);
            $("#loading").hide();
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's definitely in the right direction, however, every time the user clicks on either link or just follows the url /index.html#errors they see both pages displayed. Is there a way to make them work completely independently from each other?

Comment: @user1451687 yeah I just noticed the URL being passed is in this form: index.html#downloads and index.html#errors, and your JS parser is splitting using the character '&', and it finds none in the URL, so the parameters passed will NOT switch the appropriate pages that you expect to be included.

Comment: @user1451687 I will need to revise your code further, so the switch will work as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your earlier comment. Could you elaborate on it - what needs to follow after `$(selector).click()`? Is that supposed to be put where the checkAnchor() function is right now? I'm off to reading about it because I've never used it before....

Comment: Your helpfulness is making my day!

Comment: @RenoDimitrova yeah wait. I think it's okay now. Let me test further.

Comment: @RenoDimitrova there's the revision, see my updated answer above. Backup your core.js first and replace with the updated code above and then test.

Comment: I updated core.js and kept the switch statement as you suggested earlier but it still shows both pages at the same time no matter which link I click on. It should be (in pseudo code):if downloads is clicked show downloads.php ONLY and don't do anything else to any other or external page that may or may not be included.

Comment: @RenoDimitrova Hmm, I see, because you stated a little earlier that you want both pages to appear at the same time (see the description at the end of your question above. So if you require the original behaviour, just use your original callbacks.php code and it will work.

Comment: @RenoDimitrova This is your statement in your Q above : "This works perfectly except it uses a switch and I want to be able to see both errors.php and downloads.php at the same time, not only one or the other. Any suggestions?"

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I need it to be able to show two pages at the same time, not include them at the same time when only 1 of the links is clicked. My problem with the switch is that it replaces one page with another and I need it to "concatenate" them. In other words when a link is clicked it should reveal additional content, not change what's already included on the page. I want it to just add external pages - not remove them.

Comment: Okay, okay, I think I get it now. You wanted to sort of "append" additional data (outputted by either **downloads.php** or **errors.php**) to the `div` with an `id=content`, am I right?

Comment: Please see the updated code above, basically replace `$('#content').html(data)` with `$('#content').append(data)`

Comment: That worked!!! From previous programming experience I knew it should be a simple edit like this but I was struggling with asking the right question. Sincerely thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show both pages at once, in your callbacks.php page you should be able to do something like this (all I did was remove the switch statement):

```
include 'errors.php';
include 'downloads.php';
```

Any reason why you can't do this?

Comment: I changed callbacks.php to have only this code "<?php  

include 'downloads.php';
include 'errors.php'; 

  
?>" but when I open the main page it shows both files immediately. I'd like the user to be able to see them only after clicking on the corresponding link

Comment: it's acting as if I just put "<?php include 'downloads.php'; include 'errors.php'; ?>" directly in the "result" div in index.html..

Comment: Are you sure you put php tags in the file?

Comment: In callbacks.php? Yes. Just checked again. So it worked fine for you when you did that? May be I really should be looking for a typo somewhere....But just from trying to understand this better - since there is no if statement or case(like with the switch) in callbacks.php wouldn't that mean that it will always display both pages, no matter what link is clicked?

Comment: That is bizarre, you should just visit callbacks.php in the browser and see what's going on, for some reason the server is rendering it as a text file and not parsing the php.

Comment: ok, so when I visit it it shows DOWNLOADSERRORS. That means it is parsing the php right? But again without any other if statement how is it supposed to know which page to display based on the link that was clicked?

Comment: let me may be try to clarify again what I need to happen:1) User clicks on downloads. 2) Downloads.php is displayed without refreshing the page. 3) User then clicks on errors. 4) Errors.php appears below downloads.php on the main page. URL stays index.html#errors

Comment: @user1451687 That's exactly right. The switch statement should be there, see my solution below.